# Ideas for a correct function on my webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am having problems with a javascript function. I want to replace an icon by changing the class.

On my page, I have the following element:

```
<i class="wait icon" alt="{webui_botstatenotavailable}" title="{webui_botstatenotavailable}" id="{botname}"></i>
```

The following javascript should change the class, but it does not work:

```
function incomingBotStatusList(http_request, statusOff, statusOn)
{
if (http_request.readyState == 4)
{
    if (http_request.status == 200)
    {
        if (http_request.responseText.length < 7)
        {
            // Error
        }
        else
        {
            var botStatusList = JSON.parse(http_request.responseText);
            for (var key in botStatusList)
            {
                if (botStatusList.hasOwnProperty(key))
                {
                    var botStatusImage = document.getElementById(key);
                    if (botStatusImage != null)
                    {
                        if (botStatusList[key] == 0)
                        {
                            botStatusImage.class.innerHTML = "images/bullet_red.png";
                            botStatusImage.title = statusOff;
                            botStatusImage.alt = statusOff;
                        }
                        else if (botStatusList[key] == 1)
                        {
                            botStatusImage.class.innerHTML = "<i class=\"checkmark green icon\">";
                            botStatusImage.alt = statusOn;
                            botStatusImage.title = statusOn;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Did someone from you know how it will work?

Thanks for your help!

Best Regards
Pierre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple of problems with your code.  First, the `<i>` element is used to apply *italic* formatting to text. It is not the HTML code for an icon or an image.

Secondly, you write `botStatusImage.class.innerHTML`, but the `Element.class` does not exist, and `Element.className` is a string. It does not have an `innerHTML` attribute. So, you could write `botStatusImage.className = "new_class_name";` and this would be more correct.

You should then change the image source by calling `botStatusImage.setAttribute('src', new_url)`, where you have set new_url to the new image location.

Check out the javascript reference for the `Element` class that is returned from `document.getElementById`: [check this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element)

My recommendation, **start simple, then make it complex**.

First, try to get the icon to change without the AJAX request. Try writing a function like this:

```
function changeIcon( imageId, newUrl ){
    var element = document.getElementById( imageId );
   element.setAttribute( "src", newUrl );
}
```

Then test this function in the console by passing calling it with the URL's manually.

Once that works, don't change it!  Next add the AJAX call, and when you have the Icon url from your server response, all you do is call the function that you already wrote and tested.  That way you separate the AJAX code from the image update code and you can test them separately.

The key is smaller functions.  Build the easy stuff first, and then call those easy functions from the harder functions.  Once you know the easy function works well, it becomes much easier to find problems in the harder functions.